# error in output of given code

Tags: c++, output, codeblocks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int replace(int n[3][3])
{
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        if ((i+j)<3)
        {
            n[i][j]=0;
        }

    }
}
cout<<"new array =  : \n";
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            cout<<n[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;

    }

    int main()
    {
       int n[3][3],i,j;
         for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
             for(j=0;j<3;j++)
             {
               cout<<" \n  enter number :"<<i<<" row and "<<j<<" column   :";
               cin>>n[3][3];
             }
         }
            replace(n);
return 0;
getch();
}
```

this program is supposed to replace all those elements as 0 whose sum of indices is less than 3. the replacing takes place fine, but the not replaced numbers are not shown, instead some garbage values are displayed in output.

`[unexpected output of above program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRWn6.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

`cin>>n[3][3];` should be `cin>>n[i][j];`.

`n[3][3]` does out of bound access.